# "Element name could not be inferred" error in Firefox with Polymer 1.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm updating a little Polymer element to 1.x. It works fine in Chrome and Safari, but in the latest Firefox I get several "uncaught exception: Element name could not be inferred." errors.

Seems to be related to the html imports, because if I remove everything from the component.html except for the imports, then the errors still occur.

In the index.html I have this:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="src/element.html">
```

In the element.html this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
```

**[EDIT] - Somehow the errors disappeared. I suspect due to either a Firefox or Polymer update.**

Comment: I'm on Firefox 39.0 and Polymer 1.0--still getting this issue.

Comment: i'm havin the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache to solve the problem.

Comment: No! This does not fix this problem. If you have caching JS on when developing (which you shouldnt) and then you fix your problem, clearing cache would "solve" the problem. But the main problem was still the code (or something else... not sure)

Comment: Agreed. Do you think Polymer 1.0 should make some clean up in browsers to prevent conflicts with 0.5?

Comment: If I remember this correctly the (in my case) problem was SailsJS caching. Either way this is not Polymers problem. So no I don't think that Polymer should make any changes on this part.

Answer (score 0):

install polymer#^1.1.0 which resolved to 1.7.0
 it works for me